# Non Recoverable System Fault for new SOA Server

Tags: oracle11g, soa

We are upgrading a Oracle SOA Server to use Java 7.  When one of our Oracle SOA Composites invokes a Web Service on the new server we get the following fault.  It appears to be a connectivity issue.  I worked with our infrastructure team and had them open the firewall port for 8001, HTTP, and HTTPS.

Non Recoverable System Fault :
0oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: Error in getting XML input stream: http://192.168.40.84:8001/filestore/FileStoreServicePort?WSDL: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '192.168.40.84', port: '8001': Error in getting XML input stream: http://192.168.40.84:8001/filestore/FileStoreServicePort?WSDL: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '192.168.40.84', port: '8001'Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '192.168.40.84', port: '8001'

When I call the old server with the same Web Service it works fine.  The infrastructure team has opened up the firewall and we are still seeing the same issue.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact a firewall issue after all.

Thanks,

Tom